# Listening to the escape key

Tags: java, keylistener

I want to clear text field when the escape is pressed.

I added KeyListener to the JTextField

```
bondIDTextField.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

                if( e.getKeyCode() ==   KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE)
                    ((JTextField)e.getSource()).setText("");

            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: Why not insert the code from your keyTyped into your keyPressed method? Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code.it's working

```
    bondIDTextField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) {
            ((JTextField)e.getSource()).setText("");
        }
    }
}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use Key Bindings/input maps instead of a key listener?

Check out: 
[Responding to Button using KeyBIndings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10591669/responding-to-button-using-keybindings)

And inside the action performed just clear out your text field contents